# Eclipse - how to handle custom projects creation

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, customization

I want to develop capability in my own Eclipse feature to create projects of  my own DSL languages - in other words, I want have wizard so I can click `New > My Custom Project`, then fill in all necessary fields in wizard pages and then, after perform `Finish` I want basic folders hierarchy and template files to be created and my DSL nature to be added. I know how to create plugins/features, as good as Wizard. I can create everything in "hard-code", I mean create folders and files, but maybe there is some build-in solution to facilitate it? I found `IProject` interface with its stuff, is it a good clue?

Comment: Look at [Eclipse XText](https://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/)

Comment: Actually I have researched Xtext, but my project include also other capabilities, not only grammar tools. Additionally Xtext itself doesn't guarantee direct project creation with certain grammar (as I know, we need to create file with proper extension).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your plug-in contains a subfolder `template` with all template files, you can copy the file structure recursively into the newly created project:

```
Bundle bundle = MyPlugin.getDefault().getBundle();
String templateFolderName = "template";
for (Enumeration entries = bundle.findEntries(templateFolderName, "*", true);
        entries.hasMoreElements();) {
    URL url = (URL) entries.nextElement();
    String path = url.getPath();
    if (!path.startsWith("/" + templateFolderName + "/"))
        throw new InvocationTargetException(
                new Throwable("Unknown template file: " + path));

    // create folder or file (overwrite if file already exists)
    String targetPath = path.substring(("/" + templateFolderName).length());
    if (path.endsWith("/")) {
        IFolder folder = project.getFolder(targetPath);
        if (! folder.exists()) {
            folder.create(false, true, null);
        }
    } else {
        InputStream in = url.openStream();
        IFile file = project.getFile(targetPath);
        if (file.exists()) {
            file.delete(true, null);
        }
        file.create(in, true, null);
    }
}
```

(see the [source of the code snippet above](https://sourceforge.net/p/pacx/code/HEAD/tree/net.sf.pacx.ui/src/net/sf/pacx/ui/NewCorpusProjectOperation.java#l60))

See for example [this implementation of a customized *New Project* wizard dialog](https://sourceforge.net/p/pacx/code/HEAD/tree/net.sf.pacx.ui/src/net/sf/pacx/ui/).

Comment: Thanks for useful example :) That attract my attention to 'Bundle' mechanism in Eclipse plug-in development. But, to be honest, is it necessary to use 'Bundle'? What advantages does that solution have?

Comment: To be exact, do you mean 'template' subfolder in my plug-in project's files?

Comment: The _Bundle_ interface is pure OSGi and can be used in all OSGi-based applications, not only in Eclipse. Yes, the `template` subfolder must be part of your plug-in project that provides the wizard. Make sure, [the `template` folder is added to `bin.includes` in `build.properteis`](https://sourceforge.net/p/pacx/code/HEAD/tree/net.sf.pacx.ui/build.properties#l6), otherwise it will be missed in the exported plug-in JAR.

Comment: That works fine, but is there any easy option to create resources based on for ex. XML file with desired entries, not on template folder and it hierarchy?

Comment: Of course you can also read an XML file of your plug-in (e. g. with Java StAX) and create files based on the content of the XML files (e. g. via `IFile.create(...)`). But I have no example of this.

Answer (score 0):

I have found interesting implementation of org.eclipse.core.resources.* library on Eclipse FAQ site, and it seems to work.

```java
    IWorkspace workspace = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace();
    IWorkspaceRoot root = workspace.getRoot();
    IProject project  = root.getProject("MyProject");
    IFolder folder = project.getFolder("Folder1");
    IFile file = folder.getFile("hello.txt");
    //at this point, no resources have been created
    if (!project.exists()) project.create(null);
    if (!project.isOpen()) project.open(null);
    if (!folder.exists()) 
        folder.create(IResource.NONE, true, null);
    if (!file.exists()) {
        byte[] bytes = "File contents".getBytes();
        InputStream source = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
        file.create(source, IResource.NONE, null);
    }
```

It is very simple and do its job well, makes possible to easily initialize project's content